# X.509 libraries

Tags: c#, python, ruby, perl, x509

I'm looking for a library/module/package with which I could create and sign X.509 certificates, with the ability to conditionally add custom v3 extensions – which can be fairly complicated; for example, this bletchful OpenSSL.cnf snippet used by Kerberos PKINIT, just to represent `foo@EXAMPLE.ORG`:

```
[v3_extensions]
    subjectAltName = email:foo@example.org,
                otherName:pkinitSan;SEQUENCE:krb_princ_name_1

[krb_princ_name_1]
    realm = EXP:0, GeneralString:EXAMPLE.ORG
    principal_name = EXP:1, SEQUENCE:krb_princ_seq_1

[krb_princ_seq_1]
    name_type = EXP:0, INTEGER:1
    name_string = EXP:0, SEQUENCE:krb_principal_1

[krb_principal_1]
    princ0 = GeneralString:foo
```

Out of everything I have found for languages I know (that being Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, Bash, and some C#), using `openssl` from command line with automatically generated .cnf files... which is an ugly process. **Is there a better way to do it?** (Ruby's 'openssl' looked very nice at first, but then I got to PKINIT...)

Comment: You want to programmatically create certificates (i.e. you code to create certificates as needed) or you just want to create certificates somehow and to use them later in your code?

Comment: @user: The former. This is for my tiny internal-use-only certificate authority, and I need to issue real X.509 certificates for various services.

Comment: Read about DigiNotar and then decide if you really want to proceed down this path.  There's a lot more to running your own CA than just the code.

Comment: @wberry: I *have* read about DigiNotar. Like I said, the CA is for internal use only. (For less than ten privately-owned machines, most of which share the same 2-4 trusted users, and host absolutely nothing of importance.) The probability that I suffer the same fate is *very* small. The experience I get learning about X.509, PKI, PKINIT, and the like? Worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, I added exactly this information to the documentation for Ruby 1.9.3, which was just published today by James Britt - have a look at the [documentation for OpenSSL::X509::Certificate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html), it should answer all your questions.

Modifying the examples there to generate the particular extensions listed in your example should be straightforward if that particular extension is supported by OpenSSL itself.

For more complicated cases, e.g. the custom OtherName in your example, you may still use [OpenSSL::X509::Extension](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/openssl/ossl_x509ext.c#L273), which is not documented yet, unfortunately. The OpenSSL::ASN1 module needed for such custom extensions on the other hand has been [documented for 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/ASN1.html), and all the code/advice presented there should be applicable to 1.9.2 as well. You could also use the ASN1 module to create a multi-valued version of subjectAltName.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as 1.9.3 is released. I assume I'll have to use OpenSSL::ASN1 for such extensions? (On a related note, OpenSSL::X509::Extension doesn't seem to have an obvious way to create multi-valued extensions; e.g. two names in a single subjectAltName.)

Comment: It already works using 1.9.2 - it's only the documentation that was added recently. You may try it right away. I'll update to include more information regarding the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use OpenSSL or a direct wrapper around the library like Ruby's openssl library.

OpenSSL is a very powerful and *trusted* toolkit -- and it has the additional advantage that you can call it the same way from any scripting language.  Using the OpenSSL commandline tools, you have the advantage that you can interact with the commandline to help debug your script; you can also manually generate certs outside of your script using the same CA.

Comment: The problem with `openssl` commandline tools is that they expect the same templates to be used for all certificates. You can't, for example, issue one certificate with three subjectAltNames and another with just one but different keyUsages, with just single commands.

Comment: I've done that before and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) lets you create and manage X.509 certificates in C# and lets you add custom extensions. I believe [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) can do this as well.